# Firebase .once() in React Firebase useList hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

```js
const MyPayments = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const t = useTranslate()

  const [snapshotsList, loading, error] = useList(
    Firebase.database().ref('payments/' + Firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid)
  )

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label='table'>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>{t('payment_date')}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{t('event_name')}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align='right'>{t('amount')}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {error && console.log(error)}
            {!loading && !error &&
              snapshotsList?.map(ps => {
                Firebase.database().ref('/events')
                  .child(ps.val().event_id).once('value').then(es => (
                    <TableRow key={ps.key}>
                      <TableCell>
                        {new Date(
                          Number.parseInt(ps.key as string)
                        ).toLocaleDateString()}{' '}
                        {new Date(
                          Number.parseInt(ps.key as string)
                        ).toLocaleTimeString()}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
                        {es.val().title}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align='right'>
                        {ps.val().amount + ' ' + ps.val().currency}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))
              }
              )
            }
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  )
}
```

So I'm using `react-firebase-hooks` `useList()` to fetch the main loop data and then inside the map() loop on each record I'm fetching the related event in a once().
This seems to work because with `console.dir(es.val())` I can see the objects being fetched from Firebase, but the returning React elements are not returned.

What am I missing? I'm (guessing) that this is something about Promises coming from `then()` but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with `useEffect()`, not sure if that's the best approach but it works:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let temp: any[] = []
    temp.push(
      payments?.map(p => ({
        ...{ "event": events?.find((e) => (e.id === p.event_id)) },
        ...{ "payment": p }
      })
      )
    )
    setList(temp.flat(1))
  }, [payments, events])
```